# Ito's Lemma (CVF) on product of Poisson processes

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

I have the following stochastic differential equation:

$da(t)=\{r(t)a(t)+w(t)−pc(t)\}dt+βa(t)dq(t)$,

with $q(t)$ a Poisson process with arrival rate $λ$ and its increment $dq(t)$ is denoted by:

- $dq(t)=0$ with probability $1−λdt$
- $dq(t)=1$ with probability $λdt$

I know that using the Change of Variable formula (CVF) (=Ito's Lemma on Poisson processes), we can write the differential $dV(a(t))$ as:

$dV(a)=V'(a)\{ra+w−pc\}dt+\{V(a+βa)−V(a)\}dq$

with $V'(a)$ the differential of $V$ with respect to $a$.

Now, if I modify the initial SDE and write it:

$da(t)=\{r(t)a(t)+w(t)−pc(t)\}dt+βa(t)dq(t)+γa(t)dq_tdq^i_t$

with $dq^i(t)$ the increment of a Poisson process $q^i_t$ similar to the previous one:

- $dq^i(t)=0$ with probability $1−λ^idt$
- $dq^i(t)=1$ with probability $λ^idt$

What would be the result of applying the the CVF on that new SDE?

Replacing $dq_tdq^i_t$ by a process $dQ$,

- $dQ(t)=0$ with probability $1−λλ^idt^2$
- $dQ(t)=1$ with probability $λλ^idt^2$

I would say:

$dV(a)=V′(a)\{ra+w−pc\}dt+\{V(a+βa)−V(a)\}dq+\{V(a+γa)−V(a)\}dQ$.

But is this reasoning correct?